# IONIC2: Loading Component Preview after drag and drop

Tags: ionic2

Good morning. I'm trying to make a drag and drop form builder based on Ionic2. In that process when I drop the ionic component's code into my dropable area I can't find it rendering the exact html. For example if I pass the following code snippet into the `[innerHTML]` it does not render an input element of text type.

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I think Ionic does the transpilation before it renders actual code. But I don't know how to invoke that process so that dynamically dropped ionic component becomes visible as a preview.
Thanks in advance for your help. If you need further information please feel free to ask me. I'll be very glad to hear from you.

Comment: Transpilation is something that happens at buildtime not runtime, so no thats not the issue. Try running angulars change-detection mechanism manually using [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef). Inject it in your constructor and call `detectChanges()` after you changed the `innerHTML`property.

Comment: thanks David. But I can't use it load the ionic components like text box, radio etc

Comment: If you are using Ionic 2 you can use it very well, Ionic is based on Angular.